# Access violation reading location 0x012D363C

Tags: c++

i am using visual studio 2013. my project is library management system.after reading my file it exception of access voilation.

```
class Book {

    string edition;
    string serialno;
    string shelfno;
    int date, month, year;

public:
    Book();
    Book(char name, char aname, string edit, int srno, int shfno);
    void getbook();
    void showbook();
    void getdate();
    string bookname;
    string authorname;
};

Book::Book()
{
    bookname = "BOOKNAME";
    authorname = "AUTHORNAME";
    edition = "EDITION";
    serialno = "SERIALNO.";
    shelfno = "SHELFNO.";
}

void Book::showbook()
{
    cout << bookname << " ---- " << authorname << " ---- " << edition << "----  " << serialno << "----" << shelfno << endl;
}

void Librarysystem::showrecord()
{
    ifstream file;

    Book b;
    file.open("bookrecord.txt", ios::in);
    if (!file)
        cerr << "\n could not open file:";
    cout << "\t\t BOOK RECORD\n\n" << endl;
    while (!file.eof()) {
        b.showbook();
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&b), sizeof(b));

        if (file.eof())
            file.close();
        //cerr << "\n could not read from file:";
    }
}
```

Unhandled exception at 0x6534DF58 (msvcp120d.dll) in 3rd Sem Final PROJECT.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x012D363C. 
this is the exception

Comment: you cannot deserialize objects like that if they don't contain POD-only members. Can you show us the definition of `Book` ?

Comment: book certainly not a POD type.. never save state of objec, save its field values. You need serialization method inside of class

Comment: Please learn to indent your code; it helps us with debugging and it helps *you* too.

Answer (score 1):

We did not see the contents of `Book` class but I strongly suspect that it's using non-POD (pure object data) members like `std::string`.

In that case, you *cannot* serialize and most of all de-serialize the object using the same technique which would work with pure C types.

```
while (!file.eof())
{
    b.showbook();
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&b), sizeof(b));
```

So basically, first time, `b` is not initialized/initialized with empty values, should be OK, but after the `file.read` call, `b` holds a previous `b` state, and if there are `std::string` objects, it holds pointers on invalid memory areas (would you try serializing a pointer? would make no sense: well same here).

Simplest way would be to write proper & specific serialization/de-serialization methods in `Book` (by redefining `operator<<` and `operator>>` for instance)

Comment: even better would be define operator<< for that